# Invalid Namespace Error When Submitted ACA Files to the IRS Using the AIR UI

Tags: xml, namespaces, air, irs

I’m trying to upload a manifest and form files using the ACA transmission file upload UI but keep getting this message:

*[TPE1101] Our system detected invalid or outdated XML namespaces in the Manifest file. Please review the XML standards outlined in Section 3 of Publication 5258, AIR Submission Composition and Reference Guide, located here, correct any issues on the Manifest file, and try again*

The files I’m uploading are attached and are based on the sample files in publication 5258.  Can you tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Here's the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:ACAUIBusinessHeader xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader IRS-ACAUserInterfaceHeaderMessage.xsd " xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:tyYY1" xmlns:p1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" xmlns:p="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader">
<p1:ACABusinessHeader p2:Id="idvalue0">
    <UniqueTransmissionId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:SYS12:BB000::T</UniqueTransmissionId>
    <irs:Timestamp>2001-12-31T12:00:00Z</irs:Timestamp>
</p1:ACABusinessHeader>
<ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl p2:Id="idvalue1">
<PaymentYr>2020</PaymentYr>
        <PriorYearDataInd>0</PriorYearDataInd>
        <irs:EIN>123456789</irs:EIN>
        <TransmissionTypeCd>O</TransmissionTypeCd>
        <TestFileCd>P</TestFileCd>
        <OriginalReceiptId>OriginalReceiptId</OriginalReceiptId>
        <TransmitterForeignEntityInd>0</TransmitterForeignEntityInd>
        <TransmitterNameGrp>
            <BusinessNameLine1Txt>BusinessNameLine1Txt</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
            <BusinessNameLine2Txt>BusinessNameLine2Txt</BusinessNameLine2Txt>
        </TransmitterNameGrp>
        <CompanyInformationGrp>
            <CompanyNm>CompanyNm</CompanyNm>
            <MailingAddressGrp>
                <USAddressGrp>
                    <AddressLine1Txt>AddressLine1Txt</AddressLine1Txt>
                    <AddressLine2Txt>AddressLine2Txt</AddressLine2Txt>
                    <irs:CityNm>CityNm</irs:CityNm>
                    <USStateCd>AL</USStateCd>
                    <irs:USZIPCd>12345</irs:USZIPCd>
                    <irs:USZIPExtensionCd>1234</irs:USZIPExtensionCd>
                </USAddressGrp>
            </MailingAddressGrp>
            <ContactNameGrp>
                <PersonFirstNm>PersonFirstNm</PersonFirstNm>
                <PersonMiddleNm>PersonMiddleNm</PersonMiddleNm>
                <PersonLastNm>PersonLastNm</PersonLastNm>
                <SuffixNm>SuffixNm</SuffixNm>
            </ContactNameGrp>
            <ContactPhoneNum>1234567890</ContactPhoneNum>
        </CompanyInformationGrp>
        <VendorInformationGrp>
            <VendorCd>V</VendorCd>
            <ContactNameGrp>
                <PersonFirstNm>PersonFirstNm</PersonFirstNm>
                <PersonMiddleNm>PersonMiddleNm</PersonMiddleNm>
                <PersonLastNm>PersonLastNm</PersonLastNm>
                <SuffixNm>SuffixNm</SuffixNm>
            </ContactNameGrp>
            <ContactPhoneNum>1234567890</ContactPhoneNum>
        </VendorInformationGrp>
        <TotalPayeeRecordCnt>1</TotalPayeeRecordCnt>
        <TotalPayerRecordCnt>1</TotalPayerRecordCnt>
        <SoftwareId>SoftwareId</SoftwareId>
        <FormTypeCd>1094/1095B</FormTypeCd>
        <irs:BinaryFormatCd>application/xml</irs:BinaryFormatCd>
        <irs:ChecksumAugmentationNum>0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</irs:ChecksumAugmentationNum>
        <AttachmentByteSizeNum>1592</AttachmentByteSizeNum>
        <DocumentSystemFileNm>1094B_Request_BB000_10000101T000000000Z.xml</DocumentSystemFileNm>
    </ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>
</p:ACAUIBusinessHeader>
```

Here's the form data file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<p:Form109495BTransmittalUpstream xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Btransmitterupstreammessage" xmlns:p1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:tyYY" xmlns:p2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Btransmitterupstreammessage IRS-Form1094-1095BTransmitterUpstreamMessage.xsd">
    <p1:Form1094BUpstreamDetail lineNum="0" recordType="">
        <p1:SubmissionId>1</p1:SubmissionId>
        <p1:TaxYr>2020</p1:TaxYr>
        <p1:BusinessName>
            <p1:BusinessNameLine1Txt>Information Systems</p1:BusinessNameLine1Txt>
            <p1:BusinessNameLine2Txt>Limited</p1:BusinessNameLine2Txt>
        </p1:BusinessName>
        <p1:BusinessNameControlTxt>WORK</p1:BusinessNameControlTxt>
        <p2:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</p2:TINRequestTypeCd>
        <p2:EmployerEIN>000001966</p2:EmployerEIN>
        <p1:ContactNameGrp>
            <p1:PersonFirstNm>Margaret</p1:PersonFirstNm>
            <p1:PersonMiddleNm>P</p1:PersonMiddleNm>
            <p1:PersonLastNm>Carter</p1:PersonLastNm>
            <p1:SuffixNm>Ms</p1:SuffixNm>
        </p1:ContactNameGrp>
        <p1:ContactPhoneNum>3012223333</p1:ContactPhoneNum>
        <p1:MailingAddressGrp>
            <p1:USAddressGrp>
                <p1:AddressLine1Txt>5000 Ellin Rd</p1:AddressLine1Txt>
                        <p2:CityNm>Lanham</p2:CityNm>
                        <p1:USStateCd>MD</p1:USStateCd>
                        <p2:USZIPCd>20706</p2:USZIPCd>
                        <p2:USZIPExtensionCd>12345</p2:USZIPExtensionCd>
                    </p1:USAddressGrp>
        </p1:MailingAddressGrp>
    </p1:Form1094BUpstreamDetail>
</p:Form109495BTransmittalUpstream>
```

Comment: Not sure if you found this or if it's filtered for the post but you may have a typo in the air namespace `air:tyYY1`. I believe it should be `air:ty20` for this last reporting year

Comment: Thanks.  I did notice that, updated the XML and finally got past the error.  The XML I was copying was straight out of the IRS publication 5258.  I didn't notice the tyYY1 in there that needed to be changed.